# Buttons on webform not displayed on an equal height

Tags: css, webforms, gravity-forms-plugin

I have two buttons on a webform that are not displayed on an equal height. This happened after I updated Gravity Forms.

See http://topdek.nl/prijs/, enter a random name, email address and phone number, click 'Volgende' (Next), then choose any of the two options, and on the last step you will see two buttons on the bottom of the webform ('Vorige' and 'Verzenden'). Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4G1h.png

I was wondering if anyone would know how this can fixed using CSS?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code in your css is affecting the first button and causing the problem. Change that code to margin-bottom: 0;

```
.gform_wrapper .gform_page_footer .button.gform_previous_button {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```